# Software buttons overlap camera capture accept in Silverlight app on WP10

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

I have a Windows Phone Silverlight app that calls the CameraCaptureTask to acquire a camera picture. This works fine, except on WP10 devices which have software back, Windows and search buttons, because this navigation bar hides the "accept" and "retake" buttons in the camera capture. To illustrate the problem, I took some emulator screenshots. This is what a normal accept screen looks like on a device with hardware buttons:

[image: camera accept without overlapping buttons]

Here's how it looks with the overlapping software buttons:

[image: camera accept with overlapping buttons]

In this second screenshot, you can just about see the top of the "retake" button, the rest is hidden behind the software buttons.

Is this a familiar problem for anyone, and is there a solution / workaround? I appear to have no control over the layout of the default capture task, but rolling my own just for this silly problem seems like such overkill..

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345748/handle-the-new-windows-phone-software-buttons-winrt?

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40738897/3766231) and it'll fix things for you

Comment: Thanks guys, but those posts all apply to WinRT, not Silverlight. Also, they assume I actually have control over the view in question - I don't, this is the built-in camera task.